# Finding the source publisher in a Pub/Sub (Redis)

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

My question is two-fold:

First, in Redis, is it possible to have multiple publishers to publish messages to the same channel?

And second, if the answer to the first part is yes (which I think it is), is it possible to tell (on the subscriber end) which publisher has sent any given message?

My scenario is that I've got a server which sends events to Redis right now. And I would like to have multiple instances of it and collect all their events. I was wondering if it is possible to centralize their events in one Redis while being able to tell apart the message sources without changing the publisher code. I mean one solution is to have each server include some ID in the message but that requires changing the code which I prefer not to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, in Redis, is it possible to have multiple publishers to publish messages to the same channel?

Yes. You can even easily test it!

> And second, if the answer to the first part is yes ...

The message doesn't include the publisher, but the publisher can add its name to the message explicitly. For that you'd have to change the actual code that calls `PUBLISH` from your application - no two ways about it.